# Unable to Destroy activity Error

Tags: android

Im new in android... when i press back button it gives me the below Error...`12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.IranNara/com.example.IranNara.FirstPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at com.example.IranNara.FirstPage.onDestroy(FirstPage.java:133)
12-01 11:10:07.952: E/AndroidRuntime(3171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)`

and my activity code is:

```
    Button Nara;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
String Text="";
//private static String DBNAME = "PDA";    
private static String TABLE = "Users";
public static Integer StartFlag;
//LinearLayout linearL;
//public static String storedPersonelNo = "";

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.first_xml);                  
      Nara = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNara);
      StartFlag =0;

      final NaraAdapter mydb = new NaraAdapter(this);         
      mydb.createDatabase();       
      mydb.open();
      //System.out.println("My DB is:::: "+mydb);


      //For Login
      final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(FirstPage.this);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
      dialog.setTitle("Login");
      final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
      final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin); 

     //----------for entering on Exit Button------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit", false)){
            finish();
            return;
        }
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//********click on IranNara Button


Nara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                //Click on Cancel Button
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {      
                   Button btnLogin=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
                   Button Cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
                   dialog.show();

                   Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        editTextPassword.setText("") ;
                    }});


                   //Click on Login Button 
                   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get The User name and Password
                        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                        // fetch the Password

                        String storedPassword = getSinlgeEntry(userName,1);
                        System.out.println("storedPassword:"+storedPassword);

                        // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                        if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(FirstPage.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // Entered to Messages
                            String storedPersonelNo = getSinlgeEntry(userName,2);
                            Intent Startmain    = new Intent(FirstPage.this, Main.class);
                            Startmain.putExtra("PersonelNumber", storedPersonelNo);
                           // SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(storedPersonelNo, 0);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            StartFlag=1;
                            startActivityForResult(Startmain, 0);                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(FirstPage.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }
                      }
                   });
                }
            });     


}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------METHODS---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName,Integer n)
{  
    NaraDatabaseHandler DH = new NaraDatabaseHandler(this);         
    mydb = DH.getReadableDatabase();
    //System.out.println("My DB is:::: "+mydb);
    Cursor cursor=mydb.query(TABLE, null, " UserName=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) 
    {   
        cursor.close();  
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (n==1){
    Text= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password"));}
    if(n==2){
    Text= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PersonelNo"));}
    cursor.close();

    return Text;
}   

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mydb.close();
    //StartFlag = null;

}`
```

Comment: In My Case This Error create and Apps Crashed.

Comment: I found one solution just update apps gradle into from 28 to 29 and necessary   build.gradle file and gradle-wrapper.properties  file update . that it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `password` is not equal to `storedPassword` then `mydb` instance is null and you are trying to call `close()` method so put `NULL` check before calling close() in `onDestroy` :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(null !=mydb)
       mydb.close();
    //StartFlag = null;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

seems like the mydb is already null when you try to close it in the onDestroy method. 
Try this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mydb != null)
            mydb.close();


    }
```

Bw you should open and close the db in the getSinlgeEntry method. You dont need to close it in the onDestroy